# What is the economic word for firms buy material in credit?

Tags: reference-request, nonexpert

I am looking for the **word** relating to firms' account payable, meaning that firms buy the materials from suppliers without paying money immediately.I need the word to search on google scholar for some papers.

Similarly, the term for buyers buying stuff from sellers without paying money immediately is called "trade credit"

Answer (score 2):

**bargaining power of firms with their suppliers** as [Brown, 2009](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0929119908000990) and [Chipty,1995](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1430-9134.1995.00375.x)

The trade credit can be related to "*buyer-seller bargaining power*"